# VMD set molecule as top using script

Tags: proteins

I have 10 molecules in VMD main screen and I was wondering if there is a script command to change what molecule is the `top`.

For example, molecule `ID 9` is the top. But I want to change the `top` to 1, without using mouse.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE, Daniel. VMD has a [mailing list](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/mailing_list/), which may also be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for you help. I'm gonna ask there :)

Comment: VMD -> atomselect top ID